# Oracle Whole Database Backup

Tags: oracle, backup

What is difference between Oracle Full database Backup vs Physical/Logical?

Does Physical backup include logical?

I want to Backup Whole database what backup should i tell to DBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Physical backup is a backup made with RMAN or copying datafiles on the OS. A logical backup is a term used for data dumps using tools like datapump, export. Technically a logical backup is no a backup because you can not do a point in time recovery.

A physical backup contains logical data (for example, tables or stored procedures) so in that sense it does.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14192/intro001.htm

Comment: I want full backup so  what should i tell to dba? give me physical backup? or full backup , how is it called?

Comment: Talk to your DBA. Tell him what you want to do.

Comment: What is official name of backup format? how can assure backup is valid(it's full backup not a part) and  dba won't cheat?

Comment: Physical backup : RMAN or User-Managed Backup. Logical backup : datapump